# How to make a guild specific command for Discord using discord.py library?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I made a simple command that should print the name of the server the command is run in. I used few different decorators and got some errors.

Hi.
I'm writing a bot for Discord with some slash commands. I want to make one command specific to only one server. For now, I only want my command to print the name of the server it is used in, so I wrote this:

```
@app_commands.command(name="test")
async def test(ctx):
    guild = await ctx.guild.name
    await ctx.send(f"Test command. Server: {guild}")
```

I also tried other decorators (`@bot.tree.command`, `@bot.command` and `commands.command`)Then, in on_ready event I did:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged as {bot.user.name}')  
    srvr = await bot.fetch_guild(guild_id)   #hardcoded ID here
    bot.tree.add_command(test, guild=srvr)
    try: 
        synced = await bot.tree.sync()
        print(f"Synced {len(synced)} command(s)")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

but then, after typing `!test` in the server I want the command to be run in and I get an error that I cannot fix:

```
ERROR    discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command None
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "test" is not found
```

So, I have 2 questions.

1. How can I fix my error?
2. If I want to change it into slash command, would I have to do it in a similar way?